# Is Applock by Gizmoquip safe?

Tags: applications, malware

I tried to install an app on my tablet called [Applock](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gizmoquip.applock), by a developer called Gizmoquip (I think there are a few apps with that by different developers). AVG came up with a message saying it will install adware, and malware to steal personal information, but it has more than 2 million downloads and very few bad reviews, and I can't find any information about it online anywhere else.

Is AVG wrong, and it's actually a safe app?

(EDIT: I'm sorry if it was an innappropriate question. Without anyone saying they downloaded it and are sure without a doubt that it is malware because it broke their phone or whatever, I'm afraid I really am just asking for a more informed opinion than my own.  But, since the issue is resolved now, and you've given me some very good advice, please feel free to close the question or delete it or whatever you need to do. If I have any other problems I'll try to think more about it before posting next time. Thank you!)

Comment: Lulu, don't feel too bad about it. I understand why Matthew put it on hold (as my answer pointed out, we can only guess here); though I wouldn't have been that strict, it's a bit "border-line". Admitted, a little different phrasing and Matthew would agree with me: "Are there any clues to tell whether an app is safe", with your app taken as example, might have done – but how should you have known that :) Once you've reached 20+ rep, you can "raise doubts" in our chat room. Waiting for you there :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot give you a satisfying "100% answer", but maybe bring some light into the issue:

What [AVG reports for this app](http://www.avgthreatlabs.com/de-de/android-app-reports/app/com.gizmoquip.applock/) is:

- it includes ad modules
- specifically, it includes something called [Android/deng](http://www.avgthreatlabs.com/de-de/virus-and-malware-information/info/android-deng/) (sorry, AVG doesn't give me the English page, obviously due to my current location/IP – with some luck it will reroute you to it)

This "Android/deng" thingy seems to be ransom-ware (see e.g. [here](http://malvertising.stopmalwares.com/2015/03/malvertising-androidsvpeng-androidcrosate-androiddeng/) ; [VirusTotal reports it for another app of the same author](https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/e50521231fc9abffa52adc89571067b25e3992796eccec5715b3bbc6ff2edd6d/analysis/)).

With two places mentioning different packages of the same author "infected", that makes it at least suspicious: one can be wrong (not a rare case), but two of them for different apps of the same author rings the bells.

---

So far the first analysis. I'm still not convinced enough to scream "Malware!" straight out, neither "Safe!" – but "Special care!" never hurt. That said, what would I recommend? Different things:

- as you've already installed that app, check it with a product specialized on this. My Android-app-list for [Ad-Modules and Privacy Checker](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_admodules) will give you some choice: two of them are marked with an "IzzyOnDroid recommendation" – which is naturally what I recommend you now :)
- If all that seems to be "too suspicious and dangerous" to you, you might wish to pick an alternative app for your purpose. For that, be welcome to take a look at my list on [App Lockers](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/security_applocker).

Comment: Thank you for answering! If you think it's even a little bit suspicious, I think it's better to use one of the other apps, since it seems there are quite a few. I've installed App Lock by Domobile instead, and I might look at a few of the others in your list as well :)  Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome, Lulu! Yes, that's always the safe variant. If you found the answer useful, please condiser upvoting (tick the "up" arrow next to it) and/or "accepting" (tick the "checkmark") if it solved your issue. And enjoy your new app locker! // Btw: Another consideration is contacting the dev for clarification and see how "trustworthy" the answer seems to be.